# Does Wine support COM?

Tags: linux, wine

So first, does it support COM (Component Object Model), meaning it also emulates registry?

Second, does it support manifest files (assuming, they specify which files have what COM classes)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, Wine supports COM (and DCOM). There’s [a detailed page on COM](https://wiki.winehq.org/Wine_Developer%27s_Guide/COM_in_Wine) on the Wine wiki. The registry is stored in `.reg` files inside each Wine prefix (`system.reg`, `user.reg`, `userdef.reg`); see [the registry section in the Wine manual](https://wiki.winehq.org/Wine_User's_Guide#Using_the_Registry_and_Regedit) for details.

Wine also supports manifest files; I couldn’t find any relevant documentation, but you can see the implementation in [`ntdll/actctx.c`](https://source.winehq.org/git/wine.git/blob/HEAD:/dlls/ntdll/actctx.c).